# anchor jumping- intel xdk

Tags: html, intel-xdk

im trying to build a simple app in intel xdk. I've been trying to navigate within page with anchor jumping. this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycs1.css" type="text/css" />


    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>




</head>
<body>


    <div data-role="page" name="pageone" id="pageone">
        <h1>page1</h1>
        <a href="#pagetwo">Go to Page two</a>
    </div> 

<div data-role="page" name="pagetwo" id="pagetwo">
    <h1>page2</h1>
    <a href="#pageone">Go to Page one</a>

</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

it works well when i open it with any browser but when i run it through intel xdk it doesnt. What is the problem and how can i fix it?